# Youtube Iframe API events don't work on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Hi i want to do event when my youtube video ends. Event `onStateChange` works on desktop and android perfect but on IOS devices doesn't do change when youtube video ends because IOS is opening youtube in build in player. Here is my javascript:

```
// create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '340',
        width: '850',
        videoId: 'xnh7zOFes-4',
        playerVars: {
          controls: 0,
          showinfo: 0,
          rel: 0
        },
        events: {
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if(event.data === 0) {
        $('.mobile').fadeOut();
        $('.newsletter').css('display','flex');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this question solved by the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I think your function should be called: onYouTubeIframeAPIReady():

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '340',
    width: '850',
    videoId: 'xnh7zOFes-4',
    playerVars: {
      controls: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      rel: 0
    },
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```